# Azure B2C Applications - Do you create different applications for each mode of access?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Do you create a different B2C application in your tenant for application type? For example do you create a WebApp application, an Android application, an iOS application, and a WebAPI application if you are using all of these methods to access a system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do that or group them by type. EG: Android and iOS being native/public could use the same app registration.

Comment: Thank you. I let me implement it this way and I will check this as the answer when it is running.